# SWF object params - scale or scaleMode

Tags: object, flash, embed, swfobject

In my job I'm embedding SWF files into HTML documents all the time. I often asked myself a few things:

Is it `scaleMode="noscale"` or `scale="noscale"`? And are the values case-sensitive? I saw a few code snippets like `scale="noScale"` etc.

How is the syntax in ActionScript? Is it the Camelcase `noScale`? I don't care about the HTML standards I'd just like to know how it is from the Flash developers perspective.

Anyone has a clue? I checked Google a lot of times but I have never found something like a conformance description. I just found the Adobe page that describes the parameters and values but that does not answer any of my questions.

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 9):

Found answer in Google in 3 seconds:

> **scale** - Possible values: showall, noborder, exactfit, noscale.
>   Specifies how Flash Player scales SWF content to fit the pixel area
>   specified by the OBJECT or EMBED tag. default (Show all) makes the
>   entire SWF file visible in the specified area without distortion,
>   while maintaining the original aspect ratio of the movie. Borders can
>   appear on two sides of the movie. noborder scales the SWF file to fill
>   the specified area, while maintaining the original aspect ratio of the
>   file. Flash Player can crop the content, but no distortion occurs.
>   exactfit makes the entire SWF file visible in the specified area
>   without trying to preserve the original aspect ratio. Distortion can
>   occur. noscale prevents the SWF file from scaling to fit the area of
>   the OBJECT or EMBED tag. Cropping can occur.

[More info here](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html)

Edit: I think case-sensitivity depends on the browser, but following xhtml standards you should always use lowercase.

Edit2: `scaleMode` on the other hand is a property of `Stage` object in `ActionScript`, so it is used to set scale mode in SWF movie, that is not embeded. When you embed the swf, that param is overriden with what you've set up in your HTML.

Comment: That's the page I wrote about. But it does not answer my questions. ;) There are `scaleMode` parameters all over the web. So what's the difference? And if there is no difference, what's the right (and up to date) one (also from the Flash developers perspective)? I will edit my question. And I don't need XHTML standards when using HTML5 but thanks anyways. :)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you at first. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Found answer in SO in 2 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

If you're setting your scale mode via ActionScript, you use the `scaleMode` property of the `Stage` object. If you're setting it via JavaScript or HTML markup, you use `scale` in a `<param>` node.

Regarding capitalization, Adobe's documentation for `scaleMode` (ActionScript) has used camel case consistently for as long as I can remember (at least the last 6 years). The [current AS3 docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html) [clearly use camel case](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/StageScaleMode.html). The [article linked above](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html) is referring to `scale` in JavaScript/HTML, not ActionScript. It seems that camel case across-the-board is the safest route, you can be sure it will be supported.

Here are some `scale` examples using using SWFObject:

SWFObject dynamic:

```
var flashvars = {};
var params = { scale: "noScale" };
var attributes = {};
swfobject.embedSWF("/swf/sample.swf", "flash", "100%", "100%", "9", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
```

SWFObject static:

```
<object id="flash" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="100%" height="100%">
  <param name="movie" value="/swf/sample.swf" />
  <param name="scale" value="noScale" />
  <!--[if !IE]>-->
  <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/swf/sample.swf" width="100%" height="100%">
  <param name="scale" value="noScale" />
  <!--<![endif]-->
    <p>Place fallback content here for users who don't have Flash<p>
  <!--[if !IE]>-->
  </object>
  <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

Examples and a description of the scale options:

http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/100-width-and-height-in-browser/